# Feeds Importer and cron not running

Tags: feeds, cron

I have a Drupal 7 setup with a number of different content types, each with a common set of fields.

Each content type has its own feed, which calls a .csv that's produced from a Google Spreadsheet in tab-delimited format. Cron is set to run feeds importers daily, so when we make updates to the Google Sheet they are automatically reflected in the website

This has been working fine until recently, when we noticed the website was not updating. I checked the feeds log and see this:

[image: Feeds log]

I checked and the URL to the .csvs are working-- if I past them into the search bar I can download the file.

When I try to run the feeds manually from the "import" page, the screen just goes blank and nothing happens--no error or message. The same thing happens when I try to run cron.

Answer (score 0):

**Where is the site running?** You mention you can download the file in your browser, but I wonder if the network from the site to google is different than the network from your computer to google.

**What's in the error log in general?** When the page goes blank like that it usually means some kind of severe error happened and that should show up in the `Administer -> Reports -> Recent log entries` page for the database log. Or it might show in the php or apache error logs. The location of those logs depends on your system.

**How are you running cron?** Depending on how you run it you might see different errors. If you have drush maybe try running cron via `drush cron`.

Comment: The site is running on an external server so it is definitely a different network. However, it was working on this network no problem for the last year or so. As for the logs, I only have warnings from search: "Undefined data alteration search_api_alter_add_combined specified in index Site Index", which doesn't seem related. Cron is set to run automatically, but I've also been trying it manually through the dashboard. I don't have drush access.